# HVGA (480x320) layout is rendered in Extra High Density Android ICS device (Samsung Galaxy Nexus)

Tags: android, layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, galaxy

I have a backward compatible app which is using screen specific layout (only for HVGA). Structure of my layout is as follows:
res/layout
res/layout-480x320 (for HVGA)
layout-480x320 contains few sepcific XMLs.

Manifest is as follows:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="11"
android:maxSdkVersion="15"/>
```

When I am running this app in Galaxy Nexus (720x1280), the kayout is taken from 480x320 folder. I have built it on 2.1 target and 4.0 target. Both are resulting same result.
Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a stange change made to ICS 4.0 (or may be 3.2).

Pre ICS:
If you specify "layout-480x320" it finds and exact match and take from this folder if you device is HVGA, else it will fallback to "layout" folder.

ICS:
If you specify "layout-480x320" Android think this layout is good for any resolution which is "same OR ABOVE" 480x320, hence it does not fall back to "layout" folder. So you have to provide another folder with higher resolution.

So, now it not EXACT match but a "Range" based matching.
I dont know if this is a feature or bug. But going through the documentation it seems, it is a feature. :)